# EF Core 7: How to add WITH(NOLOCK) for SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

With EF Core 7, the solution I used before doesn't seem to work for .NET 7 projects. See [Apply WITH NOLOCK  to every table in Entity Framework Core 3.x](https://gist.github.com/bdebaere/d8e8fadb116efd717563bd72adacd3f2).

How do I implement `WITH(NOLOCK)` using a solution that is officially supported by the EF Core team: [Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors)

I tried to fix the error but since `WithNoLockQuerySqlGenerator` is using a hack to an internal EF Core API, I don't expect it to work for EF Core 7.

Sample error:

> Error CS7036
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'typeMappingSource' of 'SqlServerQuerySqlGeneratorFactory.SqlServerQuerySqlGeneratorFactory(QuerySqlGeneratorDependencies, IRelationalTypeMappingSource)'

Comment: Either rewrite your code so you don't need this kludge called `WITH(NOLOCK)` (it's really a bad idea to use it everywhere - for many reasons) - or if you **really must** have it, then use it by specifying the `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction isolation level in SQL Server for your connection

Comment: So basically you were using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078435/ef-core-what-regex-can-i-use-to-replace-table-names-with-nolock-ones-in-db-int/53082098#53082098. Using internal API is not a hack (as you can see, the classes/interfaces/methods are public), just needs to be updated   with EF Core versions, as you can see in the linked answer. I just haven't time recently to check it out with EFC7 and update it. In all the cases, it's much better than using regular expressions to append strings to arbitrary SQL.

Comment: Ivan, thank you for your feedback, let's not focus on the word 'hack'. If you get the chance of verifying what needs to be updated in EF7, kindly let us know, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Edd There you go (linked answer updated).

Answer (score -1):

##### With the use of **Regular Expressions**, append '**WITH(NOLOCK)**' via [DbCommandInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors)

###### Step 1 - Inherit from DbCommandInterceptor

- WithNoLockSqlInterceptor.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Sample.Data;

public class WithNoLockSqlInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command
        , CommandEventData eventData
        , InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        DoReaderExecuting(command, eventData);

        return result;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command
        , CommandEventData eventData
        , InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result
        , CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
    {
        DoReaderExecuting(command, eventData);

        return new ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>>(result);
    }

    private static void DoReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData)
    {
        var commandText = command.CommandText;

        commandText = GetSqlWithNoLock(commandText);
        command.CommandText = commandText;
    }

    private static string GetSqlWithNoLock(string commandText)
    {
        const string regExPattern = @"((FROM|JOIN).* AS \[*\w+\b\]*)";
        const string newValueWithNoLock = "$1 WITH(NOLOCK)";

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(commandText, regExPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            return commandText;
        }

        // APPEND WITH (NOLOCK)
        var sql = Regex.Replace(commandText, regExPattern, newValueWithNoLock, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        return sql;
    }
}
```

Regular expression explained:

1. **(**(FROM|JOIN).* AS \[*\w+\b\]***)** <= Capture all SQL that starts with **FROM** or **JOIN** and ends with **AS [TableName]**
2. **$1** WITH(NOLOCK) <= Using the captured group, append *WITH(NOLOCK)*

###### Step 2 - Register WithNoLockSqlInterceptor

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;

namespace Sample.Api.Extensions;

public static class OrmStartupExtensions
{
    private static readonly WithNoLockSqlInterceptor WithNoLockSqlInterceptor = new();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initialize Ef Core db contexts.
    /// </summary>
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureEfCore(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(AppConstants.CoopDbConnectionStringKey);

        return services
            .AddDbContext<SampleDb>((serviceProvider, options) =>
            {
                options
                    .AllowLoggingIfDebug(serviceProvider) //// This is for troubleshooting purposes only
                    .ConfigureWarnings(w =>
                    {
                        w.Ignore(CoreEventId.RowLimitingOperationWithoutOrderByWarning);
                        w.Ignore(CoreEventId.DistinctAfterOrderByWithoutRowLimitingOperatorWarning);
                    })
                    .EnableDetailedErrors()
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionString, o =>
                    {
                        o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery);
                    })
                    .AddInterceptors(WithNoLockSqlInterceptor); //<= Register the interceptor here.
                ;

            }, ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is for debugging purposes only and should NEVER enable in Production.
    /// </summary>
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder AllowLoggingIfDebug(this DbContextOptionsBuilder options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
#if DEBUG
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Startup>>();

        options
            .LogTo(message => logger.LogTrace(message), new[] { RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted })
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
#endif
        return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a ghastly idea. Adding `NOLOCK` everywhere is a [bad habit](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) and automating it even more so. Strongly consider the alternatives: use the `UNCOMMITTED` isolation level on specific transactions where you need it, or use snapshot isolation. Adding `NOLOCK` everywhere on the ORM level is telling the database server that you don't really care if you get back results that make sense at all -- possibly OK for a monitoring app, not so good if you're, say, getting customer orders.

Comment: In addition, your proposed solution will mangle queries that use subqueries, user-defined functions or table-valued parameters in their `FROM` clauses, and probably other stuff that I can't immediately see, and result in some potentially very obscure error messages that will be hard to track down.

Comment: I don't want to sound defensive here, but you must be thinking of large overly complex databases. **The question is for a very specific scenario** where there is an existing database and a similar NOLOCK approach is needed for EF7. For the sake of conversation, I wouldn't dare do this in a highly transactional eCommerce database. But for now, it satisfies the question of future proofing the existing solution.

Comment: Not exactly. My first introduction to the perils of `NOLOCK` was on a database with five tables in total -- not what I'd call complex. Unfortunately, the one table that we used `NOLOCK` on was one where it *did* matter whether or not the `GROUP BY` we did got back results. The day where we got back *nothing*, even though the table was *not* empty, was the day I learned that relying on `NOLOCK` is always worth reconsidering. If your database is *not* highly transactional, locks shouldn't be giving you trouble to the point where `NOLOCK` is needed everywhere in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I really appreciate it. I'll make sure to keep that in mind. Cheers!

Comment: Here's another thing that's bad about this "solution": it's running a regex against every SQL statement sent to the DB, which is _slooow_. The `SqlServerQuerySqlGenerator` solution is much faster because it inspects the expression tree.